# J2Me Polish Serialization

Tags: java, java-me, javabeans, polish

First of all I would like to say thanks in advance because I know this is the best website to get answers related to IT problem.

Currently I am working on Code Generation that would convert my Class Beans(simple class

files) from J2SE to J2ME now my problem is that I want to have my serialize and de-serialize

for each class and wondering how could I use J2ME Polish library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look at their web page. Serialization is pretty good explained, even with a short example. [Click me.](http://www.enough.de/products/j2me-polish/documentation/programming/serialization/)

They have also put together a example app that is quite illustrative. See *${polish.home}/samples/serialization*

HTH